# Running a loading animation using jQuery in a multi button form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `choose file` buttons and 2 `upload` buttons under each of them.

The form is flexible.

For example, you choose a file via the **first** `choose file` button but press the **second** `upload` button - the upload still works.

My objective is to now show a loading animation in the case above. I.e. show a loading animation around the **first** `choose file` button even if the **second**  `upload button` was clicked and vice versa.

So far, I've written the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Btn1").click(function(){
        $("#loader1").show();
        $("#spinner1").show();
        $("#Btn1").hide();
        })
    $("#Btn2").click(function(){
        $("#loader2").show();
        $("#spinner2").show();
        $("#Btn2").hide();
        })

});
```

It just doesn't work i.e. when I upload a file using the first choose file and click on the second upload button the loading animation runs *around the second upload button instead of the first*. Same case if i upload a file in the second choose field and press the first upload button. How do I improve this?

Comment: What should occur if user has uploaded files at both `<input type="file">` elements?

Comment: then 2 loading animations should run in their respective positions.

Comment: What should occur if second `<input type="file">` element `change` event is dispatched and user clicks second button? Only second button `.show()`, `.hide()` should be called?

Comment: yeah so what I am trying to accomplish is that if a user adds a files to the second input field and then clicks on the upload button (either one of the 2 upload buttons) then the loader should run around the second field only vice versa for the first field.

Comment: The code at Answer should render expected result given the logic that you have described

Comment: is it possible that the reasons its not working because I have actually added a 3rd input field and upload button in my form as well?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single event handler with multiple selectors utilizing attribute begins with and `:eq()` selectors.

If both `input type="file"` elements have `file.length` greater than `0`, call `.show()`, `.hide()` on both `[id^=loader]` and `[id^=spinner]` elements and `.show()` on both `[id^Btn]` elements; else if `input type="file"` element at index `0` or index `1` have `.files.length` greater than `0` call `.hide()`, `.show()` on first group of elements, else call `.hide()`, `.show()` only at second group of elements

```
var input = $("input[type=file]");

$("[id^=Btn]").click(function() {
  if (input.filter(function(index, el) {
    return el.files.length
  }) === 2) {
    $("[id^=loader], [id^=spinner]").show();
    $("[id^=Btn]").hide();
  } else {
      if (input.eq(0)[0].files.length && !input.eq(1)[0].files.length
         || input.eq(1)[0].files.length && !input.eq(0)[0].files.length) { 
           $("[id^=loader]:eq(0), [id^=spinner]:eq(0)").show();
           $("[id^=Btn]:eq(0)").hide();           
      } else {
        if (input.eq(1)[0].files.length) {
          $("[id^=loader]:eq(1), [id^=spinner]:eq(1)").show();
          $("[id^=Btn]:eq(1)").hide();
        }
      }
  }    
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: sorry I deleted my earlier comment as I overlooked your 2nd comment to my question which basically is stating the issue i am facing :)

Comment: I think since I have added another upload button and field to the form I should update my question as well since the answer above gets affected as well due to my update.

Comment: @shahz Have you read previous comment? Why are you trying to add requirements to the question?

Comment: The issue is that due to the presence of 3 fields and 3 upload buttons the given code is not working ( I could be wrong here but I have tried it and I am only getting animation around the first input field even if a file is only loaded in the second input field and I press the first upload button)

Comment: Just trying to rectify my earlier mistake and hence updated the question appropriately :)

Comment: Consider the elements of the inquiry well before posting the Question. Instead of using three `<input type="file">` or  `<button>` elements, use one `<input type="file">` element and one `<button>` element.

Comment: hhmmm you are right but now I have thought about it and I have updated the question appropriately hopefully the answers will be according to the new update now :) any update on your answer?

Comment: ok honestly I am a beginner myself when it comes to jQuery and hence I am slightly confused when you recommend that I should not use three <input type="file"> or <button> elements and instead use just one.

Comment: Perhaps another user will answer your updated question. The current Answer is to the original Question. Why are three `<input type="file">` and `<button>` elements necessary? Why do you not simply use a single `<input type="file">` element and a single `<button>` element? If we can change the requirement, the solution can be changed to suggest using only one of each element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the `change` event on the document and filter from there. That would handle all of the inputs and not rely on the clock event that has the possibility, albeit a small one, to not be associated with a file being added to the input.

Comment: are you recommending something on these lines;
 $('#p1').change(function(){
            $('#Btn1').click(function(){
                $("#loader1").show();
                $("#spinner1").show();
                $("#Btn1").hide();
            })
add the same for the second and third buttons and input fields underneath this code?